# az sql db show returns $true when database does not exist

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-az-module

Do you have any idea why it's not working correctly?

`$resut = az sql db show --name "NotExistingDB" --resource-group "rg" --server "server" | ConvertFrom-Json`

checking if database exists - it should return `false` because it does not.

`$?` :- Writing result of last command, it returns `$true` in my case but should return `$false`.

Comment: `az sql db show` command succeeds in executing, hence `$? -eq $true`. Shouldn't you be inspecting `$resut`? :)

Comment: Thanks for answer Mathias. But shouldn't it return ```$false``` because I've received error? And when I'm checking ```$LASTEXITCODE``` it gives me value 3, so that's some strange behaviour. 

It's like the error is thrown, because I'm getting ```Code: ResourceNotFound```, but I also used ```$error``` command and it doesn't show me that error in history. 
:)

Comment: ResourceNotFound comes when the resource doesnt exist, and if it exixts you will get the details of Database.

Comment: Thanks Rithwik, I know. It throws ```$true``` when the DB exists (it's working correctly - i'm getting db details). The problem is when the DB doesn't exists, because ```$?``` doesn't give me a ```$false``` result and it should I think.

Comment: It gives False , after you get error , try "$?" it gives false, i have tried it and got false.

Comment: Check this image https://i.imgur.com/DRQgTSs.png i have got the expected result.

Comment: Some time ago it was working like this for me - but it changed. Can you tell me what version of Powershell do you use?

Comment: I am using 8.3.0 https://i.imgur.com/jUQ8TWm.png

Comment: Can you tell me your Powershell or az cli version? :)

Comment: 2.40.0 https://i.imgur.com/pcoX5hL.png

Comment: And Powershell version? $psVersionTable. PSVersion - maybe newest version had some changes, because on the newest (7.2.6) I've got this problem

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CbX3nDY.png i am using newest version only

Comment: Ok, thanks. So that's crazy and now I don't have any idea what is the reason why it's working correctly for you and incorrectly for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/pull/24015

> #23514 added az.ps1 so that when Azure CLI is invoked in PowerShell, az.ps1 is called instead of az.cmd.

This change caused a number of issues and is being reverted. Though your specific issue is not listed, I can also reproduce it and it fits with the change. A fix will be released soon as far as I can see.

You can also try going back to an old version of Azure CLI to see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment by using your command, and I got the expected results as below:

[image]

I got true when the resource is found else, I got false as discussed in comments too.

I used the newer version of powershell and cli , please try to use it:

[image]

[image]